# Using Bayes Net Toolbox for Matlab

Tags: matlab, bayesian-networks

I want to use Bayes Net Toolbox in matlab , especially  [score_dags(data, ns, dags) function](https://code.google.com/p/bnt/source/browse/trunk/BNT/learning/score_dags.m?r=64) .

I have:

-3 nodes

-All combinational subset of these nodes that create [dag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (will be 25 dags)

-Array with size (3,30) where each rows represent the data of nodes (e.g. row 1 for node 1)

When I call the function , if  the parameter “data” is the array , and the parameter “dags” is the 25 dags then what it “ns” parameter?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The result of the function is always the same, regardless of the data array:
 -9.76978793044148 -8.42426751081712 -8.42426751081712 7.89691186178541 ,,,,, etc
Why?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "ns" is the node sizes, where `ns(i)` is "...the number of values that node i can take on, or the length of node i if i is a continuous-valued vector."

In other words, "ns" holds the domain sizes of each node. For example, if node i can take on values {'red', 'green', 'blue'}, then `ns(i)` = 3.

It is documented in the [.m file for mk_bnet](https://code.google.com/p/bnt/source/browse/trunk/BNT/general/mk_bnet.m?r=64) (`score_dags` passes "ns" to `score_family`, which then passes it to `mk_bnet`).